# Marketing cloud hubexchange app's security review

Tags: marketing-cloud, appexchange, security-review, hubexchange

I recently hear the news that **Salesforce is asking for the security review of hubexchange apps**.I'm not sure this is only for security purpose or they are migrating the hubexchange apps to appexchange.

So i tried to find out the exact process for applying the security review of such hubexchange apps but i didn't find any.**Current docs and videos point in the direction of force.com apps.**

So i have several questions around this.

> 1.does Salesforce want to migrate the apps from Hubexchange to Appexchange or this is only for security review purpose?
>
> 2.I know Salesforce team helps when we want to apply for security review of hubexchange apps but it would be great if we have exact docs
>   and videos which can guide us.

Please guide if anyone has the knowledge of this process.